# Dell XPS17 factory image reinstall of windows 7

Tags: windows-7, dell-xps

After a year of using win7 on Dell XPS17 I want to restore it to the factory image. However if I press f8 on boot and select repair computer, I only get the repair options, nothing to reinstall windows.

how to reinstall?

Comment: What are the repair options shown? Did you make any recovery disks when you first got the computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my 30 secondes Google-search: [How to factory restore a dell xps computer?](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20111123190035AAuTusP):

1. Turn on/Restart the computer
2. As the computer starts, press <kbd>F8</kbd> on the keyboard until the "Advanced Boot Options"-menu appears on the screen
3. Press the <kbd>Down Arrow</kbd> on the keyboard to select `Repair Your Computer` on the "Advanced Boot Options"-menu, and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Specify the language settings that you want and then click <kbd>Next</kbd>
5. Log in as a user who has administrative credentials and then click <kbd>OK</kbd>
6. Click `Dell Factory Image Restore`
7. In the "Dell Factory Image Restore"-window, click <kbd>Next</kbd>
8. Click to select the `Yes, reformat hard drive and restore system software to factory condition`-check box.
9. Click <kbd>Next</kbd>. The computer is restored to the default factory configuration
10. When the restore operation is completed, click <kbd>Finish</kbd> to restart the computer. The software is now installed as it was when the computer was first received.

Comment: thanks but I've done that but I don't have the option to Dell Factory Image Restore

Comment: do you still got a recovery partition ? if yes you can try manualy recover windows  :
http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/software-os/f/3524/t/19331267.aspx#19697868

Comment: found it, it was under this dell datasafe stuff

Comment: now if there was a way to get all the junk dell put on this image, i wish I asked for a CD when I bought it 2 years ago